# "As a consequence", "in order to", "is seen as" - bad style according to Word?

Tags: synonyms, writing-style, formality

Starting with one of the newer versions of MS Word, I receive quite a lot of suggestions on how to improve my text by the spelling and grammar check. Often, they involve adverbs related to structuring the text.

I'm not a native speaker, so I sometimes lack the "feeling" whether a certain word or phrase fits into the context and style of text. In general, this means that I find spellchecking very helpful overall. In those particular cases, however, I am not really sure whether I should really follow them.

Some examples (the left side showing what I wrote and the right side what Word suggests):

> "**As a consequence**, three topic need to be considered" -->
> "**Therefore**, three topics need to considered"
>
> "**Oftentimes**, we need to ..." --> "Often we need to..."
>
> "Action A needs to be done **in order to** prepare..." --> "Action A needs to be done **to** prepare"
>
> "Punctation is **taken into account**" --> "Punctation is
> **considered**"
>
> "The event **is seen as** something which..." --> "The event **is** something which..."
>
> "issues **in the area of** topic A" --> "issues **in** topic A"

Are all of those examples really a case of bad style, meaning the suggestions of Word are clearly superior?
Or can they be seen as a case of very "strict" stylistic corrections, meaning the original would still be acceptable in formal writing?

Thank you for your input!

Comment: You'll find some style guides that consider some styles too flowery. Are you serious about 'oftentimes'? '[I]s seen as' may be needed instead of 'is', but it may just be padding. // In these areas, you're right that 'feeling' is necessary to be able to select the _mot juste_. Word's suggestions may or may not be good ones.

Comment: MSWord has a lot of different settings for style, its suggestions to you are based on the options selected there. I'm not at a pic just now, but from memory you can change things such as 'formality' and 'wordiness'. I suggest checking if the option settings are appropriate for your needs. Also, if you are unsure of the register if a word like 'oftentimes', use google to see how and when others use it, not just to check its meaning.

Comment: MSWord has exactly one different setting for style: none whatsoever at all. Do not use it. For anything. Ever. It does not know what the word "style" even *means*. Heck, it does not even know what the word "word" means. Why are you using it. Do not use it. If you ask an idiot for advice, they will give you idiot advice. If you ask MS Word for advice, it won't even give you idiot advice. Exhibit A: above. Stop using it right now this very second, or suffer the consequences.

Comment: I'm now voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question about English, but a bug report about a piece of broken software. That will never get fixed, because it can't.

Answer (score 1):

three topic -> topic**s** . 
"As a consequence" is often used in the form: "As a consequence of...".

'Oftentimes' is not used very often.

"In order to " can often be replaced by a "to", sometimes one of them fits better than the other.

"Punctuation is considered" is probably more generic, but both can be correct depending on what follows.

The last 2 change the meaning so depend heavily on what you really want to say.

"seen as" vs "is" should be quite clear: "is" is factual. "is seen as" is not necessarily so.

"the issues in topic A" vs "in the area of topic A" depends on what topic A is and whether the issues are in topic A itself or in something related (the area)